# What is the difference between the stack and the heap?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system

A program is divided into 4 parts: Stack, data, code, heap.

I know what each of them are as data structures (like used in Java), but what is their difference (and definition) in operating systems?

Answer (score 2):

> A program is divided into 4 parts: Stack, data, code, heap.

That is not an accurate starting point.

A program is divided into program sections with various attributes.

- Read Only/No execute (which you call data)
- Read Only/Execute (which you call code)
- Read/Write (which encompasses both heap and stack).

A stack is simply a block of memory that is allocated and freed using push and pop operations.The allocations and frees are usually implemented using a stack pointer register.

A heap is one or more blocks of memory that can be allocated and freed in any order and various sizes. The operating system has no knowledge at all of program heaps. The are managed by libraries linked to the code (although the operating system will have heaps of its own). The operating system simply sees these a blocks of memory.